# Error Starting up Camunda Zeebe 8.3.1 with docker-compose

Tags: memory, docker-compose, jvm, camunda, zeebe

After i have upgraded the CAMUNDA_PLATFORM_VERSION from 8.3.0-alpha3 to 8.3.1.
There is error during startup as shown:

```
zeebe          | Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
zeebe          | [0.002s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "GC Thread#0" - pthread_create failed (EPERM) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
zeebe          | #
zeebe          | # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
zeebe          | # Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
zeebe          | # An error report file with more information is saved as:
zeebe          | # /usr/local/zeebe/hs_err_pid8.log
zeebe exited with code 1
```

I'm using the same environment and same docker-compose way of starting up Zeebe.
Command : docker-compose up zeebe

This is my docker-compose.yml for **zeebe**

```
  zeebe: # https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/platform-deployment/docker/#zeebe
    image: camunda/zeebe:${CAMUNDA_PLATFORM_VERSION}
    container_name: zeebe
    ports:
      - "26500:26500"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      -ZEEBE_BROKER_EXPORTERS_ELASTICSEARCH_CLASSNAME=io.camunda.zeebe.exporter.ElasticsearchExporter
      - ZEEBE_BROKER_EXPORTERS_ELASTICSEARCH_ARGS_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ZEEBE_BROKER_EXPORTERS_ELASTICSEARCH_ARGS_BULK_SIZE=1
      - ZEEBE_BROKER_DATA_DISKUSAGECOMMANDWATERMARK=0.998
      - ZEEBE_BROKER_DATA_DISKUSAGEREPLICATIONWATERMARK=0.999
      - "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:9600/ready" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
```

I have try to increase the memory allocation for the JVM but the server still won't start up.